# Details in derivation of distance from a point to a line

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm abusing this platform because I don't understand the formula presented on the Wikipedia article [Distance from a point to a line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)

On the page it states on the algebraic proof that:

The line with equation $ax + by + c = 0$ has slope $−a/b$, so any line perpendicular to it will have slope $b/a$ (the negative reciprocal). Let $(m, n)$ be the point of intersection of the line $ax + by + c = 0$ and the line perpendicular to it which passes through the point $(x_0, y_0)$. The line through these two points is perpendicular to the original line, so

$\dfrac{y_0-n}{x_0-m}=\dfrac{b}{a}$

Thus, $a(y_0-n)-b(x_0-m)=0$ and by squaring this equation we obtain
$a^2(y_0-n)^2+b^2(x_0-m)^2=2ab(y_0-n)(x_0-m)$

How would you obtain the last part? I even tried asking ChatGPT but the answer was you cannot.

Comment: ChatGPT is notoriously bad at math!

Comment: Squaring both sides of $a(y_0-n)-b(x_0-m)=0$ gives $a^2(y_0-n)^2-2ab(y_0-n)(x_0-m)+b^2(x_0-m)^2=0$ (though may introduce a second spurious result) and adding $2ab(y_0-n)(x_0-m)$ gives what you call the last part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last equation is obtained by squaring both sides of the equation

$$ a(y_0-n) + b(x_0 -m) = 0.$$
To do this they used the formula

$$ (A - B)^2 = A^2 + B^2 - 2AB $$

where $A = a(y_0 - n)$ and $B = b(x_0-m)$. The final equation in your post is

$$ A^2 + B^2 = 2AB $$

which is indeed equivalent to $(A-B)^2 = 0$ since

$$ A^2 + B^2 = 2AB  \iff A^2 + B^2 - 2AB = 0 \iff (A-B)^2 = 0. $$